# How to restrict a particular user to access the particular webpage

Tags: php

I want to restrict users to access particular webpages in my applicatipn. In my application I have 4 webpages like `Mumbai`, `Delhi`, `Bangalore`, `Kolkata` and I have havie 4 users say `User1`, `User2`, `User3` and `User4`. All users are Admin.

My requirement is that all 4 user can't access `Mumbai` page, `User1` can access only `Delhi` page, `User2` and `User3` can access only `Bangalore` page and `User4` can access only `Kolkata` page.

For Mumbai page I used

```
if($login_session['login_user'] != 'User1, User2, User3, User4')
{ 

   echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=Admin-Dashboard.php">';
   exit();       

}
?>
```

And for Delhi page I used Following code but it is not working

```
if($login_session['login_user'] != ' User2, User3, User4')
    { 

       echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
       echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=Admin-Dashboard.php">';
       exit();       

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: A user can't be User1, ... , UserX at the same time...
If u want to take that approach u need to save the users in an array and do something like : `if (!in_array($login_session['login_user'], $validUsers){ ... }` with `$validUser = array('User2', 'User3);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `'User1, User2, User3, User4'` is a string. You need to `explode()` that or somehow make sure that the users are in an array:

```
$allowed_users = array('User1','User2','User3');
if (!in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users)) {
   echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=Admin-Dashboard.php">';
   exit();       
}
```

Comment: @user2636930 Why not?

Comment: I used following code for Delhi page , Delhi page can access only by user 1

$allowed_users = array('User1','User2','User3','User4');
if (!in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users)) {
   echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=Admin-Dashboard.php">';
   exit();       
}
?>

Comment: I used this for Delhi Page For user1 But other Users also Access the Delhi Page Actually User1 having access to Delhi Page   


$allowed_users = array('User2','User3','User4');
if (!in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users)) {
   echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=Admin-Dashboard.php">';
   exit();       
}

Comment: I Used This code also
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = 'User1';
$login_session = array(
    'id'            =>  session_id(),
    'login_user'    =>  $_SESSION['username']
);var_dump($login_session['login_user']);
$allowed_users = array('User2','User3','User4');
var_dump(in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users)); 
if (!in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users)) { 
   echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=include1.php">'; 
   exit();}